# Xamarin Forms Webview html video not playing on iOS devices

Tags: ios, xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a Xamarin Forms (4.2) app that uses a WebView. This is the Webview.xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             BackgroundColor="#66B1D1"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             x:Class="ParentsApp.Pages.WebViewPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
                <StackLayout>
                    <WebView x:Name="WebView" Source="https://www.testsite.com/testvideo.aspx"></WebView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The WebViews source points to a basic Html page that contains a video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <video poster="https://ljtest.blob.core.windows.net/test/b5de01eb-2ecd-41e8-a7d6-2099b11ebbcd_thumbnail.jpg" style="max-height: 345px; max-width: 614px;" controls preload="none" loop muted>
                <source src="https://ljtest.blob.core.windows.net/test/b5de01eb-2ecd-41e8-a7d6-2099b11ebbcd_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4">
             </video>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

We see the video thumbnail with a play icon which reacts when clicked but the video does not play.

I have an iPhone 5s (12.4.3), iPhone X (13.1) and iPad (5th gen 13.2.3). If i open safari on the same iOS device and go the same html page the video plays.

The video plays on Android devices ok.

**28 Nov Update**

---

I've created a solution containing a basic Xamarin forms app (has nothing but a WebView) and basic web app (single html page containing a video element) and you can see this on [github](https://github.com/WilliamDag/VideoTest2019/)

I have also read about the latest [iOS video policies](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) thinking it may be related but to reiterate if i use safari on any of our iOS devices and navigate to the same page that the Xamarin WebView points to the video plays.

In production the videos would be hosted in Azure Storage. To rule out any possible issues with this the thumbnail and video in this example are hosted on the test website.

Comment: Can you please provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you `AzureBlobStorageAccount` start with http, you have to config [ATS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#opting-out-of-ats) to allow http request in your iOS project.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi Jack - have added code to show the .xaml webview page and updated the html video with a real storage account, thumbnail and video. The storage account has secure transfer turned on so we're always accessing it via https

Comment: I loaded the html page as a local file and it works on my side. I waited about 5 seconds(loading) and the video starts playing. I uploaded my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/webView-load-html-file).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi Jack, i've added a bare minimal reproducible example to github - see the update section in the original post - you should be able to deploy the app to an iOS device. The issue only presents itself on actual devices, emulators play the video ok. Hopefully you be able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try if use a `WkWebView` and set `MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to false will solve your problem?

In the `custom renderer`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(MyCustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
    public class MyCustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration() { MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false});
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `customWebView`:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And in `Xaml`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <app1:CustomWebView Source="https://videotest2019.azurewebsites.net/" Uri="https://videotest2019.azurewebsites.net/" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. I found i needed to explicitly set IsEnabled="True" on the CustomWebView but otherwise this works and the video plays.